# Querying multiple tables with a where clause in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

Forgive my ignorance with Linq to SQL but...

How do you query mulitple tables in one fell swoop?

Example:

I want to query, say 4 tables for a title that includes the following word "*penguin*".  Funnily enough each table also has a field called TITLE.

Tables are like so:

[image]

I want to query each table (column: TITLE) for the word "*penguin*".  Each table is referenced (via foreign key) to a parent table that is simply called **Reference**, and is linked on a column called REF_ID.  So ideally the result should come back with a list of REF_ID's where the query criteria was matched.

If you can help you will be richly rewarded....... *(with a green tick ;)*

The code I have works for just one table - but not for two:

```
var refs = db.REFERENCEs
.Include(r => r.BOOK).Where(r => r.BOOK.TITLE.Contains(titleString)).Include(r => r.JOURNAL.AUTHORs)
.Include(r => r.JOURNAL).Where(r => r.JOURNAL.TITLE.Contains(titleString));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario a while back and ended up creating a view that unioned my tables and then mapped that view to a LINQ-to-SQL entity.

Something like this:

```
create view dbo.References as

  select ref_id, title, 'Book' as source from dbo.Book
  union all
  select ref_id, title, 'Journal' from dbo.Journal
  union all
  select ref_id, title, 'Magazine' from dbo.Magazine
  union all
  select ref_id, title, 'Report' from dbo.Report
```

The mapping would look like this (using attributes):

```
[Table(Name="References")]
public class Reference {

  [Column(Name="Ref_Id", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
  public int Id {get;set;}

  [Column]
  public string Title {get;set;}

  [Column]
  public string Source {get;set;}
}
```

Then a query might look like this:

```
var query = db.GetTable<Reference>().Where(r => r.Title.Contains(titleString));
```

Comment: That was a route I went down - but then I couldn't do any complex query result shaping, e.g. querying the author name as well.

Comment: Which table has the author name in it? You could put more info into your view or define associations between your view and other tables in your LINQ model ...

Comment: Each table has a M-M relationship with an AUTHOR table.

Comment: Also - I want to be able to have a flexible search eventually - so different fields may be queried, and the UNION will not work in this way as all tables must have the exact same fields specified in the resulting view.

Comment: Ah, I see. You could just add the Authors association to your model ... The polymorphic search, however, is more complicated - that would have been useful info to put in your original question. : )

Comment: You might be able to put all the common fields into the base Reference entity and then define an inheritance mappings for the sub-types - Book, Journal, etc.

I'll need to take a look at the MSDN docs to figure out how to do that again.